# How to make all polygons into triangles

Tags: mesh, faces

I need to create test file for my program. But it only accepts polygons with 3 vertices - triangles as input. How can I convert all polygons of some object into triangles?

I know how to select all faces, but how to split them into triangles.

Comment: more answers to the same question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30846/converting-from-quads-to-triangulated-mesh/30847#30847

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can select all the faces and go to *Face > Triangulate Faces* in the 3D View header (or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for the same effect) while in *Edit Mode*.

As [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/55/ideasman42)  pointed out in the comments, *Face > Poke Faces* will also triangulate the mesh by adding a vertex in the center of each face and fan-filling around the vertex, it may give preferred results for certain cases, for example, cylinder caps.

You could also add a 'Triangulate' modifier to the object and apply it:

[image]

Visualisation of the two methods:

[image: Triangulate and Poke Faces Visualisation]

Comment: One other method, `Mesh -> Faces -> Poke Faces`, maybe worth adding to answer.

Comment: @ideasman42 How does Poke Faces actually differ from triangulation? What else does it do?

Comment: edited answer explaining what poke-faces does,

Comment: Another method would be: `Mesh -> Clean up -> Split Non-Planar Faces`, then set *Max angle* to `0`.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an easy way to do it through Blender's Python API:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='FIXED', ngon_method='BEAUTY') #if you want a faster way
```

or

```
bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY') #If you want nicer cuts
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `bpy.ops` so the context doesn't matter? (given the object whose mesh should be triangulated)