# Converting from quads to triangulated mesh

Tags: animation, makehuman

I have a mesh that has been created in MakeHuman. I have imported it into blender to apply some python scripts on it. But, they require that the mesh must be triangular. So, my question is, is there any way to convert from quad to triangular mesh in blender or even MakeHuman?

Comment: Ctrl-T in edit mode

Comment: @RayMairlot This question has a lot more answers, that are missing on the proposed duplicate. Should we reverse the duplicate direction?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise This does have more answers, but then in my answer I show 2 methods. It's a similar amount of information just in a different number of answers, so I'm not really sure. Can always flag this question and ask a mod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select your object. Enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to tirangulate.

[image]

The tools has a few options:

[image]

**Beauty** Split the quads in nice triangles, slower method.

**Fixed** Split the quads on the 1st and 3rd vertices.

**Fixed Alternate** Split the quads on the 2nd and 4th vertices.

**Shortest Diagonal** Split the quads based on the distance between the vertices.

Comment: You type too fast cegaton :)

Comment: @Jerryno this site has pushed me to. Answers pop within seconds...

Answer (score 5):

While, in your case, cegaton's answer is likely simpler, just for completeness there's also the Triangulate modifier:
[image]

After applying the modifier and going into Edit mode, the cylinder looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

And to complete the answers: You don't have to triangulate the mesh for python at all if you don't care about vertex order..you can use something like [mesh.tessfaces](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_63_2/info_gotcha.html#info-gotcha-mesh-faces) which will represent your polygons triangulated.