# Double Triangulate in Blender

Tags: mesh

Is there any way to automatically make this
[image: double-triangulated plane as desired]

from this:

[image: default-triangulated plane]

I guess it should be called "double-triangulation" or "cross-triangulation", but there's no trace of it in the docs nor anywhere on the Internet.

I need to split in two all the longest individual edges of triangulated mesh, and connect resulting vertices to closest vertices already exist, so the triangles I've recieved during the first triangulation were splitted in two.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In blender it's called ["Poke faces"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/poke_faces.html), but you have to perform it on quads to get the shape you are mentioning.

Here's a tut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z2x3Wvzono

So:

1. run the "Tris to Quads" operator on all the faces
2. then run the "Poke Faces"

[image]

Comment: Here's a related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/how-to-make-all-polygons-into-triangles

Answer (score 7):

**Dissolve and Poke.**

[image]

Select a long edge, the select similar by length to select all.

<kbd>X</kbd>Limited dissolve.

Finally poke the faces.