# Is there way to create triangular faces on mesh?

Tags: mesh

I've created a mesh and I want to create a ribbed side on it. I want it to look like this (colored side):
[image: Result]
The only way I've found is to select every odd/even vertex, drag them down and merge them. But it's too long to select odd vertexes, so is there another way to create that "triangular faces" (sorry, I don't know how to call it right)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make all polygons into triangles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/how-to-make-all-polygons-into-triangles)

Comment: @Emir, unfortunately, no. In that case I still need to select triangles that I don't need and delete them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way to get around the tedious "select every other vertex" is to use Checker deselect.

[image]

You find it in the select menu. You can even select 2, then skip 1 or select 1 and skip 3 etc.

[image]
After you have the selection, move the vertices and merge them or whatever.

[image]

Comment: Cool! Checker deselect is the thing I need. Thank you!